# jQuery $.proxy scoping

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

May be a trivial question but I can't find a solution. The following code:

```
$.extend(Module.prototype, {
    initialize : function() {
        ...
        $('.afx-list a').on('click', $.proxy(function() {
            this.onClickEventHandler(/* argumentIwantTohave - clicked element */);
            return false;
        }, this));
        ...
    },
    ...
    onClickEventHandler : function(/* argumentIwantTohave */) {
        var currentScrollTop = 0,
            destinationScrollTop = 0,
            offsetScrollTop = 0;

        currentScrollTop = $(document).scrollTop();
        destinationScrollTop = $('a[name=' + $(this).attr('href').split('#')[1] + ']').offset().top;

        // Resolvin the problem with missing 1px when scrolling to destination
        if(currentScrollTop < destinationScrollTop) {
            offsetScrollTop = 1;
        } else {
            offsetScrollTop = -1;
        }

        $('body').animate({
            scrollTop: destinationScrollTop + offsetScrollTop
        }, 1000);
    },        
});
```

now, within the '$('.afx-list a').on('click', $.proxy(function()' function I need both variables - the Module.prototype scope to invoke the 'onClickEventHandle' and clicked element scope to pass it as an argument.

Can I have two contexts at once? For:
1. Module.prototype
2. Clicked element

I've tried something like this

```
        $('.afx-list a').on('click', $.proxy(function() {
            this.onClickEventHandler(/* argumentIwantTohave - clicked element */);
            return false;
        }, { clicked : /* dont know what is the refference */, module : this}));
```

but I don't know what reference should be placed for the 'clicked' property.

Comment: Can you give the proxy function an `event` argument, and pass that on to `onClickEventHandler`. Then use the `event.target` property? http://api.jquery.com/event.target/

Comment: Yes, that seems to work and that is the solution for me. Thank You.

Comment: You could even reduce the proxy call to `$.proxy(this.onClickEventHandler, this)`, and just have the `event` argument for your on click handler.

Comment: Yes You are right - seems to be more readable now